# Error when compiling C program that has multiple header files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, clang

I have `kmeans_seq.c` and `bikmeans_seq.c` files. The file `bikmeans_seq.c` includes two headers: `kmeans_seq.h` and `bikmeans_seq.h`. When I compile `bikmeans_seq.c` using `gcc bikmeans_seq.c -o bikmeans` I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_euclidean_dist", referenced from:
      _points_assignment in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
      _partition_clusters in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
      _standard_deviation in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
  "_find_max", referenced from:
      _standard_deviation in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
  "_kmeans", referenced from:
      _main in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
      _partition_clusters in bikmeans_seq-5c462b.o
     (maybe you meant: _bisecting_kmeans)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure what this error is. Can someone hint me why I am getting this error? Thank you.

Comment: without the source that'll be difficult. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: how are those two C files related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sources is a bit difficult but try this:

```
gcc -Wall bikmeans_seq.c kmeans_seq.c -o bikmeans
```

Even if this will work I would suggest to use a makefile.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the OP is using clang, according to this line of the output shown `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Toby In the question he wrote "When I compile bikmeans_seq.c using gcc bikmeans_seq.c -o bikmeans I get this error", but I had the same doubt

Comment: Must be an Apple system. They messed things up completely when they moved from gcc to clang but linked `gcc` to clang. 80% of Apple users now think they use gcc.